# Insert into mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql

first post here and a newbie at php programming.

I am trying to insert $val(2) into mysql database. My code is as follows:

```js
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$hostname = "xxx";
$val= "2";

$connection=mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("database",$connection)
or die("Could not select examples");

$url = "http:xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"; //url here
$str = file_get_contents($url);

$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (data)
VALUE ('".$val."')";
   
$ins= mysql_query($test);
if(! $ins )
{
 die('Could not insert: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

When i run the code, there is no error printed out, but no data is being inserted into the table. Can someone point out the problem. I would appreciate the help.

Addendum:

I didn't include the lines:

```
$url = "http:xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com";    //url here
$str = file_get_contents($url);
```

in my first post.

The real solution is to change:

```
$test to $sql
```

and to comment out the 2 lines below

```
file_get_content($url) 
$str = file_get_contents($url);
```

These 2 lines has to be placed on top (before the $username= "xxx" line) for it to work. Apologies for the misleading question.

Comment: Can you try replacing `value` with `values`?

Comment: Is it intended that you're supplying $test to mysql_query instead of $sql?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I tried changing value to values, still not working

Comment: @BenY My mistake, it should be $sql instead of $test, unfortunately, it still isnt working

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: You say no error is printed, so you're saying that either it doesn't enter the if-block, or is `mysql_error()` empty?

Comment: @Qirel I tried adding an echo statement in the if block, but it doens't echo anything. My guess it doens't enter the if block

Comment: You could do it in a single-line, though: `$ins = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` -- if it doesn't die, the query should be successful. You can also `echo $sql;` to make sure your query looks alright.. And make sure that you're actually using names in the table that matches the one in your query.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? `mysql_` was *removed* in PHP7. If *nothing at all* is printing (when something should be printed), you have a fatal/syntax error somewhere, and you'll need to enable [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and check your logs.

Comment: @Qirel I added that line and for some reason I cannot explain, it works like a charm! Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Qirel im running php 5.4, anyways it's working now so all is fine and dandy. Once again, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your INSERT method as shown below (You missed "S" at the end of "VALUE"):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable(data) VALUES ('".$val."')";
```

On the other hand please be aware that there are different variables on the line below and you can use "slq" instead of "test" as shown below:

```
$ins= mysql_query($sql);
```

For more information have  a look at [PHP Insert Data Into MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed VALUE to VALUES, still not working

Comment: There is nothing printed on the php page, so im assuming there's no exeptions

Comment: I replaced the if block with this line $ins = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); as suggested by Qirel and change VALUE to VALUES and it works! Thanks for the help

Comment: VALUE is acceptable in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html `{VALUES | VALUE}`

Answer (score 2):

You have an SQL error here:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (data)
 VALUE ('".$val."')";
```

`VALUE` should be `VALUES`.

You should always check for errors when something does not work as intended ( [mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error) in this case).

Also, you should not use the `mysql` extension any more. It has been deprecated for ages. Look into either [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) for a better and safer extension.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed VALUE to VALUES, still not successful

Comment: FYI: It's not an error. Both are valid in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score 2):

*The **fact** of the matter* is that you were calling the wrong variable in:

```
$ins= mysql_query($test);
```

which should have been `$sql` and not `$test`

```
$ins= mysql_query($sql);
```

as per the query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (data)
 VALUE ('".$val."')";
```

which both `VALUES` and `VALUE` are valid in MySQL. Some have the misconception to believe it must be `VALUES`. **Both are valid.**

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

From the manual:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

And error reporting would have told you about the undefined variable `$test`.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with **prepared statements**.

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed as of PHP 7.0. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I changed the variable $test to $sql, but it still wasn't working. Turns out the real problem was that i inserted a file_get_contents right before the mysql_query($sql) line. This somehow messed up the whole program big time. My main goal was actually to read from a website and insert it into database, which explains the file_get_contents. Upon commenting out this line, it works. I will keep a mental note on deprecation and sql injection

Comment: @user You're welcome, but in not showing your full / real code, was a tad misleading, wouldn't you agree? ;-)

Comment: I totally agree with you, will do so next time.

Comment: @user In all fairness to future readers of the question/answers; you should update your question with the real code you're using. That way an actual solution would have been posted rather than being misleading/falsified where you did state here in comments that that wasn't the real problem in having used `VALUE` which I mentioned scattered here in there and under an answer that in MySQL, both `VALUE` are `VALUES` are valid http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html and the 2nd issue was that you were using the wrong variable. People may downvote some of the answers because of this.

Comment: I didn't think file_get _content() would have any affect which is why i didn't include it, how wrong I was. Apologies, I have modified the question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$hostname = "xxx";
$val= "2";

$connection=mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("database",$connection)
or die("Could not select examples");

$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (data)
 VALUES ('".$val."')";
 
$ins= mysql_query($sql);
if(! $ins )
{
 die('Could not insert: ' . mysql_error());
}
```